# How to store max id from mysql query into a php variable?

Tags: php, mysql

This isn't working for me:

```
$query = mysql_query(" SELECT max(id) FROM chat_records ");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    echo $row['id'];
}
```

How can I get it to work?

Comment: AJ has it below.  Whenever you use an aggregate function (`SUM, MAX, COUNT`), it's a good idea to provide a column alias with the `AS aliasname` syntax. And if you use `fetch_assoc`, it is necessary.

Answer (score 4):

Change your query to this:

```
SELECT max(id) AS id FROM chat_records
```